# java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /target/classes/META-INF/annotations/hudson.Extension when building Jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins, plugins

I have found a plugin for using StatsD with Jenkins (https://github.com/joemiller/jenkins-statsd-plugin) - however the HPI needs building because it is not available in Jenkins plugin repository nor is it aailable to download.

I followed the official instructions at https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial, but the `$ mvn package` always exits with `[ERROR] java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: ~/src/jenkins-statsd-plugin/target/classes/META-INF/annotations/hudson.Extension`.

I have tried using java 6, 7, 8 *and* 10 but to no avail.

I wonder if anybody else has come up against this problem building Jenkins plugins and what they're solution was?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I fixed this problem by setting JAVA_HOME to point to Oracle’s version of Java 8. It appears maven uses the  JAVA_HOME  environment variable, not your $PATH.

Edit: For extra context, Jenv was responsible for the version of Java in my $PATH.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to post here my findings from various sources that worked for me as the accepted answer alone was not sufficient.

- I had to downgrade my Java version back to 11 from 13.
  [I used this quick solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37469464/how-to-generate-an-hpi-plugin-from-an-existing-project-for-jenkins/59557553#59557553), which doesn't require you having JDK and Maven installed locally.
- Moreover, deleting `target/classes/META-INF/` directory before executing `mvn install` again was necessary.
- Lastly, passing `-Djenkins.version` parameter to Maven [is required](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-52024?focusedCommentId=362625&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-362625) so you need to do something like `mvn -Djenkins.version=2.164 install`

Comment: Working on building the selenium plugin with Java 11 (instead of 8). Setting the jenkins version in the maven command got me past this issue

Comment: This can solve the issue for everybody who wants or needs to use Java 11. Not sure why I have to specify the jenkins version on the command line?

Answer (score 1):

This will definitely get resolved by using java 1.8.* JDK.